# Remove scrollbars from sidebar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to emulate a nice scrollbar that i saw on the website https://doughellmann.com/blog/. (You must be on a screen bigger than 955px to view the sidebar) However, my sidebar is fixed and if it overflows in the y direction a side bar appears so on the screen you have two scroll bars - One for the sidebar and the other for the page. However, I don't want that. I want the user to go the bottom of the sidebar and then fix it self like it did on this webiste. Here's how my code looks right now

```
.sidebar{
    display: block;
    background-color: #1056b1;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

 .content-on-the-right{
    margin-left: 31%;
  }
```

Does anybody know how i could solve this problem using vanilla javascript or reactjs or even css if that's possible?

Comment: To be honest that's a weird behaviour... You'll need to hide the overflow on the sidebar and scroll the content programmatically byt changing the Y position or the margin-top of the child that contains the sidebar content. But since SO is not a free programming service, try it, post you attempted so far (you WILL need some JS) and then we can help solving the remaining issues

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this but I believe this will get you started on getting what you want.  For this example, let's say your sidebar has an `id` of `sidebar`.

When the `window` loads, you can add an `EventListener` that will call a `function` that will check the elements offsets. You can take it from there:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", DoScroll, false);

function DoScroll() {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
  var sidebarHeight = document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetHeight;
  var winHeight = window.innerHeight;

  var offset = sidebarHeight - window.pageYOffset;

  if (offset < winHeight) {
    sidebar.style.position = "fixed";
    sidebar.style.bottom = 0;
  } else {
    sidebar.style.position = "static";
  }

}
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VashTS/hwjhwu9a/) that demos this.

P.S. I know the name of the `function` kinda sucks but am a bit burned out... you can give it a more descriptive name.